# LinqToExcel to EPPlus

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus, linq-to-excel

I am moving a project to Azure. The project is using LinqToExcel, to read data from an Excel file.

LinqToExcel has a couple of dependencies, which is not supported in a Azure WebApp. So, i am migrating the code to EPPlus.

But, how could a lookup like this, look in EPPlus?

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelFile);
var results = from c in excel.Worksheet(mySheet)
                   where c["columnName"] == Value1.ToString()
                   select c;

myValue = results.First()["MyColumnName2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Its been years since I have looked at LinqToExcel but from what I remember it treats columns as properties the properties of objects - kind of slick actually.  But EPPlus does not have that kind of encapsulation built it.

Using something like this file as an example:

https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel/blob/master/src/LinqToExcel.Tests/ExcelFiles/Companies.xlsx

[image]

and say you want all companys > 200 employees and CEOs with `s` in their names, about the best you can do is this:

```
var fi = new FileInfo(@"C:\temp\Companies.xlsx");

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
{
    var wb = pck.Workbook;
    var ws = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    var headerRow = ws.Cells
        .Where(cell => cell.Start.Row == 1)
        .ToList();

    var ceoCountColNum = headerRow
        .First(cell => cell.Value.ToString() == "CEO")
        .Start
        .Column;

    var empCountColNum = headerRow
        .First(cell => cell.Value.ToString() == "EmployeeCount")
        .Start
        .Column;

    var rows = ws.Cells
        .GroupBy(cell => cell.Start.Row)
        .Skip(1)
        .Select(g => g.ToList())
        .Where(row =>
            (double) row[empCountColNum - 1].Value > 200 &&
            row[ceoCountColNum - 1].Value.ToString().Contains("s"))
        .ToList();

    Console.WriteLine(rows.Count);  //return 2
}
```